# Populating and parsing bi-dimensional arrays in awk

Tags: multidimensional-array, awk

I am trying to produce a report with awk from a log file that looks like this:

```
==== Header line ====
Error Code : 3001 (DB Conn. Failled)
App. Name  : 'APLICATION_01       '
Details    : Details is not relevant
and details are multiline
with no fixed lengh, nor number of lines
==== Header line ====
Error Code : 2002 (User login Failled)
App. Name  : 'APLICATION_02       '
Details    : User 'Abcd' is locked
==== Header line ====
Error Code : 3001 (DB Conn. Failled)
App. Name  : 'APLICATION_02       '
Details    : Connection to DB "XYZ" failled
with DB error "SQL1234"
==== Header line ====
Error Code : 2001 (Any stupid error)
App. Name  : 'APLICATION_01       '
Details    : This is not relevant
and details are multiline
with no fixed lengh, nor number of lines
==== Header line ====
Error Code : 3001 (DB Conn. Failled)
App. Name  : 'APLICATION_01       '
Details    : This is not relevant either
```

*(Updated the initial input file to have App. Name value enclosed in single quotes and padded with blanks up to 20 chars.)*

The desired output is something like:

```
App. Name / Error               Occurences
==============================  ==========
APLICATION_01                            3
    3001 (DB Conn. Failled)              2
    2001 (Any stupid error)              1
APLICATION_02                            2
    2002 (User login Failled)            1
    3001 (DB Conn. Failled)              1
```

... so, the output is grouped by application, with a totalization, and then a sub-total, for each error code per application.

Ideally, the output would be sorted, showing first the applications with more errors, but the sorting is not mandatory.

I started to code this awk ... I know I am far from my target, but that was what I could do so far ...

```
awk -F "[:]+" 'BEGIN {
err_str=""; app_name="" ; total=0
print "App. Name / Error               Occurences"
print "==============================  =========="
}
/^Error Code/ {
   err_str=$2 }
/^App. Name/ {
   app_name=$2  
   arr_app[app_name, total]++ 
   arr_app[app_name, err_str]++  
   } 
END {
   for (app in arr_app) {
      print "app " app
      print "app[app] " arr_app[app]
     }
}' app.err
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
App. Name / Error               Occurences
==============================  ==========
app  APLICATION_010
app[app] 3
app  APLICATION_020
app[app] 2
app  APLICATION_02 2002 (User login Failled)
app[app] 1
app  APLICATION_01 3001 (DB Conn. Failled)
app[app] 2
app  APLICATION_02 3001 (DB Conn. Failled)
app[app] 1
app  APLICATION_01 2001 (Any stupid error)
app[app] 1
```

The printings in the '`END`' on this code are not intended to get my target. They were added only for a debug purpose.

I used 0 as an index (using 'total' var) for the grand total, as I know 0 will never be a valid "Error code".

Apparently, rather than handle '`arr_app`' as a bi-dimensional array, my code is merging the data.

Any hints on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Do you have (or can you get) GNU awk? What does `awk --version`or `awk -V` tell you and what OS are you on?

Comment: This is supposed to be run in many different servers, so, as much portable/standard the solution is, that is better, but I think gawk would be acceptable on all servers.
The output is:
# awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.5

Comment: OK, it's easy enough to come up with a POSIX solution. FYI that version of gawk is **extremely** out of date - it's 17 years old and we're now on gawk 5.1.0 which has a ton of bug fixes and new functionality.

Comment: @EdMorton that (the fact that it is a very old version) does not surprise me :( ... Most of servers on this customer are RHEL, but versions may vary between 6.* (maybe 5) and 8.* ... I tested in another server and that has "GNU Awk 4.0.2" ... so, like I said, as much portable/standard the solution is, the better. TKX in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{
    val = $0
    sub(/[^:]*: */,"",val)
    gsub(/^[ \047]+|[ \047]+$/,"",val)
}
/^Error Code *:/ {
    err = val
    errs[err]
    maxWid = (length(val) > maxWid ? length(val) : maxWid)
}
/^App\. Name *:/ {
    app = val
    appsCnt[app]++
    appErrsCnt[app,err]++
    maxWid = (length(val) > maxWid ? length(val) : maxWid)
}
END {
    occWid = length("Occurences")
    fmt = "%-" maxWid+4 "s  %" occWid "s\n"
    printf fmt, "App. Name / Error", "Occurences"
    printf fmt, "=================", "=========="
    for (app in appsCnt) {
        printf fmt, app, appsCnt[app]
        for (err in errs) {
            if ( (app,err) in appErrsCnt ) {
                printf fmt, "    " err, appErrsCnt[app,err]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
App. Name / Error              Occurences
=================              ==========
APLICATION_01                           3
    3001 (DB Conn. Failled)             2
    2001 (Any stupid error)             1
APLICATION_02                           2
    2002 (User login Failled)           1
    3001 (DB Conn. Failled)             1
```

The above doesn't sort the output. If you want sorted output and can't rely on having a newer version of `gawk` with arrays of arrays and `sorted_in`, then I recommend you do it in 3 stages:

1. Use `awk` to generate the output you want in a CSV format, e.g. `app,err,cnt`, then
2. Pipe that `awk` output to `sort` to sort it however you like, then
3. Pipe the `sort` output to a new `awk` script to format it as you finally want.

but I'll leave that as an exercise since you said sorting was optional and it's not hard to do given the above script as a starting point.

Comment: thanks a lot for your solution. Just have 2 questions: 1) which would be a minimum awk version to have "arrays of arrays"? I tried that first, w/o success, but I was thinking the issue was only my code, and not related to the awk version. 2) I just tested successfully in one of my servers, but then I realized that the application name in the initial file is like 'APPLICATION_01    ' (enclosed in single quotes, and padded with blank spaces). How can I cleanup it, removing the single quotes (having issues to escape it here)

Comment: You're welcome. 1) 4.0. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History for when arrays of arrays, sorted_in, and other features were introduced to gawk. 2) If the data in the example in your question isn't truly representative of your real data then fix the example in your question so we can see what it really looks like and test with it.